# What's the REST API endpoint for a list of your Twitter notifications?

Tags: twitter

If you go to [Twitter](http://twitter.com) and click on "Notifications" in the main navigation, you'll see a list of things that have been done to you - someone favorited your tweet, someone retweeted your tweet, someone mentioned you, etc... I went down the [entire list of API endpoints](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) and could not find one that resembled these notifications. Does it exist? I don't need realtime push notifications - I just need a list of the hundred or so most recent notifications.

[image]

Comment: did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

This API call exists - but it is unsupported and requires you to sign your request with the **official** Twitter Client keys

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/activity/about_me.json
```

How you get those keys is left as an exercise in creativity.  Use of such undocumented APIs is prohibited by Twitter.  Use of someone else's keys is also prohibited.